# How do you add and subtract repeating decimals?

Tags: arithmetic

I am currently in $8$th grade and I need to know if it’s like normal subtraction or it’s different because the number is infinite. For example: $$. \overline {5} - . \overline {05}$$ Would that equal $.45$ or $.\overline {45}$? I need to know, because I've searched everywhere for an answer and I cannot find anything on at at all.

Comment: Welcome. I, for example, not have understood nothing.

Comment: Are you asking about how to do subtraction the way you learn in school, starting from the right, when there is no right-side end to the numbers?

Comment: Well, remember that, if $a-b=c$, then $a=b+c$. At least that lets you check possible answers quickly.

Comment: It equals neither of those. It is $0.5$.

Comment: Search for _subtract repeating decimals_ . You will find several web sites, at least one video.

Comment: Convert them both to fractions and subtract the fractions!

Comment: If I didn't know better I'd say you were a finitist trying to set a trap. The answer is that you can't because you cannot perform an infinite number of operations in finite time. In the case of repeating decimals, there are tricks which may be used, but this can get quite delicate when the lengths of the repetends differ.

Comment: As an example of what @AmaanM and the existing answer suggest: Suppose you want to subtract $0.5 - 0.0\overline{5}$. You can convert both values into their respective fractions $1/2$ and $1/18$ (there are standard ways to do that), and then subtracting them yields $9/18 - 1/18 = 4/9 = 0.\overline{4}$. Notice that if you add these values decimally, you get $0.\overline{9} = 1$.

Comment: If it's the "infinite" part that's causing problems, try taking smaller steps. What's $0.5-0.05$? $0.55-0.055$? $0.555-0.0555$? Do you see a pattern as you keep tacking on more digits?

Comment: If you know what $\overline{05}$ is, you should find the correct result. If you don't know  what $\overline{05}$ is, you should not use this notation.

Answer (score 1):

If you try it with decimals directly,

$0. \overline{5} - 0.\overline{05} = .55555555.... - .05050505....=.50505050.... \rightarrow 0.\overline {50}$

However, if you recognize that $0. \overline{5}$ is $\dfrac {5}{9}$ and $0. \overline{05} = \dfrac {5}{99}$, you can subtract the fractions to get $$\dfrac {5}{9} - \dfrac {5}{99} \rightarrow \dfrac {55}{99} - \dfrac {5}{99} \rightarrow \dfrac {50}{99} = 0.\overline {50}$$

To wit: anything that repeats in a single digit will have a denominator of $9$; anything that repeats with two digits will end in $99$, and anything repeating with $n$ digits will have a denominator of $10^{n}-1$.

ETA: There is also a trick for determining repeating decimals from *Rapid Calculations* ([from Google Books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Rapid_Calculations/LhIFAAAAMAAJ?hl=en)...)

> For the **denominator** take as many nines as there are recurring figures in the decimal, and as many zeroes as there are non-recurring figures. For the **numerator** take the entire number and deduct all the non-recurring figures.

So for $0. \overline{5}$, the denominator would be $9$ (only one recurring digit) and the numerator would be $5$, so we get $\dfrac {5}{9}$.  For $0. \overline{50}$, the denominator is $99$ (two recurring digits) and the numerator is $50$, giving us $\dfrac {50}{99}$.  For $0.4 \overline{25}$, the denominator will be $990$ (two recurring digits, one non-recurring digit) and the numerator will be $421 (425-4)$ to give us $\dfrac {421}{990}$.